# NuGet package DurableTasks 2.9.4 installed, but the class DurableTaskOptions it contains shows 2.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I have Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask version 2.9.4 installed. I'm using Visual Studio. But when I look at the class DurableTaskOptions in this package, it shows 2.0.0.0. I need an option that was added to 2.2.0 for DurableTaskOptions.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]